# Does Cygwin do any virtualization?

Tags: windows, unix, shell, cygwin

So,I came across Cygwin the other day.From what I understand,it basically adds linux system calls and libraries functionality to Windows.My question is whether it does this by creating  a thin virtual machine & then acting as hypervisor between linux and windows interface like most vm softwares.

Comment: You did read the [FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.api.everything), right?

Comment: Yes, I did @DanielB . So it basically it creates a DLL file with all the necessary system calls so no virtualization involved ,is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It does not.
As reported on the main page https://www.cygwin.com/ :

> What...
>       ...is it?
>
> Cygwin is:
>
> a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide
>   functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.  a DLL
>   (cygwin1.dll) which provides substantial  POSIX API functionality.
>
> ...isn't it?
>
> Cygwin is not:
>
> a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must  rebuild your
>   application from source if you want   it to run on Windows.  a way to
>   magically make native Windows apps aware   of UNIX® functionality like
>   signals, ptys, etc.  Again, you need to build your apps from source if
>   you want to take advantage of Cygwin functionality

There is no virtualization. You need to compile the programs for cygwin to run them.